# Text wrapping in Outlook while using Range to HTML Conversion with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to format `.HTMLbody` in email in a way to put an image containing a chart next to table with the data based on which the chart was created.

To convert the range with data into HTML I use Ron de Bruin's Range to HTML code.

My goal is to get mail body like below:
[image: Result to achieve]

I am getting this:
[image: What i have now]

My code.

```
Private Sub SendingMail()

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim strPic1 As String
    Dim strPic1Inserting As String
    Dim strTextOfMessage As String

    strTextOfMessage = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:10pt'>" & "Hello ,<br><br>Please Find Report Attached.<br><br>In case of any questions please do not hesitate to contact us." & "</p>"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").ChartObjects("Wykres 1").Chart.Export SCIEZKARAPORT & "TempPicture.png"
    strPic1 = SCIEZKARAPORT & "TempPicture.png"
    strPic1Inserting = "<br/>" & "<img src='cid:" & "TempPicture.png" & "' height=250 width=500>" & "<br/><br/>"

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Attachments.Add strPic1
        .HTMLBody = strTextOfMessage & RangetoHTML(Range("qqq")) & strPic1Inserting & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Solution:
Unfortunately `<div>` tags did not work for me. But when investigating why this might be, I found a post stating that `<table>` tags might do just that. I achieved what I was hoping for using the line below:

```
.HTMLBody = strTextOfMessage & "<table align='left'>" & RangetoHTML(Range("www")) & "</table>" & strPic1Inserting & "<br clear='left'><br>" & .HTMLBody
```

Comment: Put both your table and your image into a `<div>` with `style="float:left"` (the table) and `style="float:right"` (the image). Then put both into a father `<div>` with `style="display:flex".` Find a sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9qjekac7/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately <div>  tags did ot work for me. But when investigating why this might be, i found a post stating that <table> tags might do just that. And they did. I achieved what i was hoping for using line below: 
.HTMLBody = strTextOfMessage & "<table align='left'>" & RangetoHTML(Range("www")) & "</table>" & strPic1Inserting & "<br clear='left'><br>" & .HTMLBody